# Flutter GetX ( GetConnect )

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I using latest version of Flutter 3.10.5 and get package version 4.6.5. I have problem with GetConnect..

The problem is next.. I always getting null for response body and also for status code..

some pictures in below..

- Here is my ApiService

[image]

- Here is initialization and usage

[image]

[image]
[image]

So, the problem is that i getting just null ..ther's not any response, any statusCode etc.. And the problem is same with any endpoint, not just with this one from pictures..

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by adding `allowAutoSignedCert = true;`

[image]